# "Get charged" vs. "get charge", "got charged" vs. "gets charged"

Tags: grammaticality

> - My phone doesn't get charged.
> - My phone doesn't get charge.

Which statement is grammatically correct here?

Actually, I don't know the use of *get/got*.

> - My phone got charged.
> - My phone gets charged.

Which one is correct here? And why?

Comment: If I read your question correctly, I must say it has already been addressed at the [“Your order has shipped”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107286/your-order-has-shipped) thread. Whether that is the right interpretation or not, it needs further clarification. The get/got secondary question is of a standard suitable for ELL, not this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re referring to financial rather than electrical matters, ‘my phone doesn't get charged’ means that no debit is made to your account. ‘My phone doesn't get charge’ is ungrammatical.

‘My phone got charged’ and ‘My phone gets charged’ are both grammatical, but whether they are appropriate can be judged only by the context.

This use of *get* is known as the *get*-passive. It is rare, but occasionally found in conversation, and even then mostly with just a few other verbs.

Comment: Can you give me an example to show the difference between gets charged and got charged?

Comment: _Gets charged_ is present tense, so you might say ‘My phone gets charged every month.’ _Got charged_ is past tense, so you might say ‘Last week my phone got charged for a call I didn’t make.’

Comment: What are the other places at which I can use get? I am asking just to make myself clear on this "get".thanks.

Comment: The _get_-passive is mostly used with _married, hit, involved, left_ and _stuck_.

Comment: And, What if I am talking with the reference of electricity matters? Then, how will I say that?

Comment: The same considerations apply. If you're not sure, you really need to consult a qualified English teacher or a grammar book for non-native speakers.

Comment: Can you suggest me a Grammar book which I can go through and polish my Grammar skills? thanks.

Comment: A good general reference is 'An A-Z of English Grammar and Usage' by Leech and others, but it really depends on what your needs are and what is available where you live.

Comment: I am an Indian. And, I have huge problem with the grammar part. As you can see, I am not naive for English. But, I want to polish my skills. Is that book good for me? I don't want beginner's book. Can I start reading that book?

Comment: It's a reference book, so you wouldn't normally just sit down and read it from cover to cover. I still think you should consult a qualified English teacher.

Comment: As you are watching my writing style, do you really think that I need an English teacher? Actually, I am reading newspapers, magazines, novels these days to improve my vocabulary and understanding. One suggested me to explore language as much as I can, so as to have good hand at the language.

Comment: If you're looking for grammar books you need guidance on whatever may be available where you live. Have a look at what's available in the local bookshops.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid the *get* construction entirely.

1. If you mean it is malfunctioning, write:

   > My phone won't charge.

   or

   > My phone doesn't charge.
2. If you mean you don't pay for it, write:

   > My phone isn't billed.

   or

   > I am not charged for using my phone.

Comment: in which reference have you used this "charge" here. Can you take any other example because charge is confusing me.

Comment: I hope my edits have made this clear.

Comment: @hellodear2: Many verbs in English behave rather surprisingly: I melted the butter <==> The butter melted. She closed the door <==> The door closed. We cooked the turkey slowly in the main oven (<==>) The turkey cooked too slowly in the smaller oven. The direct object in the transitive usage can (with some verbs) be made the subject in a transformed intransitive sentence. The latter usage is called the 'ergative' usage. With your example: I charged my phone yesterday (<==>) My phone's so old it charged very slowly. (I've tinkered with the latter two pairs to make them sound more natural.)

Answer (score 1):

1.My phone doesn't get charged is correct.It might mean that there is something wrong with the phone.
2.My phone doesn't get charge is grammatically wrong.Because it's not passive.
3.My phone got charged is correct.It means someone charged my phone.
4.My phone gets charged is also correct.
(The different between sentence 3 and 4 is like the difference between past and present)
and about your example:
I charged my phone yesterday is correct.
But My phone's so old it charged very slowly is wrong.
You should write (It gets charged very slowly)

Comment: Or *It charges very slowly* I don't know anyone who would say *it gets charged very slowly* unless there is a charge time setting on the charger that you can set to "Slow" (Trickle) or "Fast (Quick)"